# Error in seq.default(1, length(cts_splt), by = 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Tags: merge, arguments, sign, seq

I am trying to merge two data sets and thus trying to cut some NA data with the following code:

```
vedba <- read.csv(vedba_in)
head(vedba)
vedba$Start <- as.POSIXct(strptime(vedba$Midway,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),tz="GMT")
head(vedba)

##cut data
cts <- cut(as.numeric(vedba$Start),breaks=c(breaks[1] - 3600,breaks))
## which dive do each vedba event belong
cts_splt <- strsplit(as.character(cts)[!is.na(cts)],split=",")
cts_splt <- unlist(cts_splt)
cts_splt <- cts_splt[seq(1,length(cts_splt), by=2)]
substring(cts_splt,1) <- "0"
cts_splt <- as.numeric(cts_splt)
dive_no <- match(cts_splt,as.numeric(begin))
```

Yet when I run it, I receive the following error:

Error in seq.default(1, length(cts_splt), by = 2) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument

I am stumped and can't fix it. I have used this argument before and haven't had the error so something must be wrong with my data set. Any clues?

I have uploaded an image of what my data looks like.

[My vedba_in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThCs8.jpg)